# What's wrong with this C++ program?

Tags: c++

I just have an header file and and an .cpp file i am just passing an value to function but it gives me an error

main.c

```
#include "me.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    me("http");
}
```

me.h

```
#ifndef ME_H_
#define ME_H_
#include <string.h>
class me {
public:
    me(std::string u);
    virtual ~me();
};

#endif /* ME_H_ */
```

me.cpp

```
#include "me.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
me::me(std::string u) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
cout << "help";
}

me::~me() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

I am getting an error

```
In file included from ../src/me.cpp:8:
../src/me.h:13: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘u’
../src/me.cpp:12: error: prototype for ‘me::me(std::string)’ does not match any in class ‘me’
../src/me.h:11: error: candidates are: me::me(const me&)
../src/me.h:11: error:                 me::me()
make: *** [src/me.o] Error 1
```

Comment: @Erik is correct.  And as usual, the first error message is the one to pay attention to: the compiler says it's confused on the line of me.h declaring `me(std::string u);`

Answer (score 21):

`#include <string>` instead of `#include <string.h>`

string.h is the C string header, accessible in C++ as `<cstring>`

`<string>` is the C++ header that defines `std::string`

Answer (score 3):

you want `#include <string>` instead of `#include <string.h>`